# how to replace data frame rows containing column names with column labels in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

consider my labelled df1 below

[image]

This is my second dataframe df2

[image]

I want to change item column in df2 such that if its rows contains any names of df1, that string is replaced by the column label like below

[image]

any approach to achieve this is highly appreciated.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(low = rep(1,3),
                  med = rep(2,3),
                  high = rep(3,3),
                  other = rep(0,3))
label(df1$low) <- "is it low"
label(df1$med) <- "is it med"
label(df1$high) <- "is it high"
label(df1$other) <- "is it broken"



df2 <- data.frame(item = c("lowYes", "medNo", "high"),
                  value = c(12, 10, 14))

df3 <- data.frame(item = c("is it low:No", "is it med:Yes", "is it high"),
                  value = c(12, 10, 14))
library(stringr)
df2$item <- str_replace(df2$item, grep(df2$item, names(df1)), label(df1)) # not for all rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `label` from the 'df1' and create a named `vector` (`unlist`), then use the named vector in `str_replace_all` for modifying the 'item' column by matching the `key` value with the substring in 'item' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(Hmisc)
keyval <- df1 %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ str_c(label(.x), ":"))) %>% 
  unlist
df3 <- df2 %>%
   mutate(item = trimws(str_replace_all(item, keyval), whitespace = ":"))
```

-output

```
df3
           item value
1 is it low:Yes    12
2  is it med:No    10
3    is it high    14
```